# MySQL Deletion Query, Multiple Inner Joins

Tags: java, mysql, database

I want to delete an "order" from my database using the primary key, orderID. The orderID is a foreign key in orderItem, OrderItem has a foreign key in foodItem called foodItemID, foodItem has a foreign key in menu called menuID.

Below is my query:

```
            "DELETE FROM orders, orderitem, fooditem, menu " +
            "USING orders " +
            "INNER JOIN orderitem " +
            "WHERE orderID = " + "'" + orderID + "' " + " AND orders.orderID = orderItem.orderID " +
                    "INNER JOIN foodItem " +
                    "WHERE orderItem.foodItemID = foodItemID.foodItemID " +
                    "INNER JOIN Menu " +
                    "WHERE foodItem.menuID = menu.menuID";
```

I am coding in JAVAFX..
The error I receive is:

> Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INNER JOIN foodItem WHERE orderItem.foodItemID = foodItemID.foodItemID INNER JOI' at line 1

Comment: `inner join ON`, not `WHERE`

Comment: Also, this has nothing to do with Java, you have a problem with your query, not your java program per se

Comment: Finally `"WHERE orderID = " + "'" + orderID + "' "` this is an sql injection waiting to happen. Use prepared statements instead.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca please post it as an answer.

Comment: @Dropout right on. done

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca upvoted, hopefully OP will notice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't join `WHERE`, you join `ON` something. So

```
"DELETE FROM orders, orderitem, fooditem, menu " +
"USING orders " +
"INNER JOIN orderitem " +
"ON orderID = " + "'" + orderID + "' " + " AND orders.orderID = orderItem.orderID " +
"INNER JOIN foodItem " +
"ON orderItem.foodItemID = foodItemID.foodItemID " +
"ON JOIN Menu " +
"ON foodItem.menuID = menu.menuID";
```

Also, this part

```
"ON orderID = " + "'" + orderID + "' " + "
```

Is a [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) waiting to happen. You should use prepared statements instead. How you use them depends on what library/framework you're using to connect to the db (which you didn't specify).